# Typescript generics. Can't pass instance of B to a argument a: T where T extends B. Why?

Tags: typescript, generics, parametric-polymorphism, subtyping

I have class:

```
class X<T extends B> [...]
  // this.p.a :: B | null
  methodA(a: T):void {[...]}

  methodB(): void {
    if(this.p.a){ // :: B
      this.methodA(this.p.a) // Error
```

As you can see, I'm relaying on `T` being any type as long as it extends `B`, and then I'm passing some property to it of said type `B`. However Typescript can't infer that `B` is a type that satisfy `T` type parameter in the last line of above code snippet.

Error message:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
```

**Why is this not working?**
**Should I change any offending type declaration to `B` instead of `T` and relay on inheritance?**

Comment: The if is inside the X class?

Comment: Oh, yes. It is inside `methodB` inside class `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because someone might use `X<T>` where `T` is a subclass of `B`, and then `this.p.a` might be a `B` that is not a `T`.  To know the best way to resolve the error, we'd need to know more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How `B` can not be valid type for `T` when `T extends B`?

Comment: Suppose `B = {x: string}` and `T = {x: string, y: string}`.  Then `T extends B`, and if `this.p.a = {x: "foo"}`, then `this.p.a` is a `B` that is not a `T`.

Comment: Ok. I get it `<T extends B>` means => any type as long as it's strictly bigger then `B`. Hmm. How do I make it `bigger or equal to`?

Comment: No, `T extends B` means the caller of class `X` gets to choose `T` and can choose it to be equal to `B` or a subtype (what you are calling "bigger").  The implementation of `X` has to work for _all_ valid choices of `T`.  If the caller chooses `T` that has more members than `B`, then your code doesn't work.